# The requested URL was not found on this server 404

Tags: http-status-code-404

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Hello dear friends.I have two days to come up with this code.Please let me know if someone has experience .Many thanks....

I deleted the file .htacces, disabled the plugins, changed the permissions but it didn't work.